# How do I selectively apply a glare filter to one individual object?

Tags: objects, compositing-nodes, effects

How do I selectively apply a glare filter in the compositor to say my stars without affecting other object emissions in this scene like the moon and window?

[image]

Here's the scene for reference; the stars, the moon, and window are each their own separate object.

Comment: my answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/69513/2217) should help you.

Comment: Related:https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46382/how-can-i-make-a-part-of-a-texture-glow/46389#46389 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35853/one-part-of-the-render-layer-glowing